# how to replace only NAs by matching ids from another dataframe in r

Tags: r, dplyr

My df1 looks like

```
PID End_record_date
123 NA
123 15-08-2020
234 NA
234 19-07-2020
345 NA
```

my df2 has matched ids

```
PID Record_date
123 13-10-2018
234 14-07-2019
345 20-08-2020
```

Expected result i need

```
PID End_record_date
123 13-10-2018
123 15-08-2020
234 14-07-2019
234 19-07-2020
345 20-08-2020
```

I need only NAs to be filled without disturbing other values

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` :

```
inds <- is.na(df1$End_record_date)
df1$End_record_date[inds] <- df2$Record_date[match(df1$PID[inds], df2$PID)]
df1

#  PID End_record_date
#1 123      13-10-2018
#2 123      15-08-2020
#3 234      14-07-2019
#4 234      19-07-2020
#5 345      20-08-2020
```

---

Other option is to join the two dataframes and select the first non-NA value from the two.

This can be done in base R as :

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'PID'), End_record_date = 
           ifelse(is.na(End_record_date), Record_date, End_record_date))
```

Or in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'PID') %>%
  mutate(End_record_date = coalesce(End_record_date,Record_date)) %>%
  select(PID, End_record_date)
```